# facebook connect error

Tags: facebook, cakephp

i am using cakephp facebook plugin. when i click login. i get the following error

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

I am trying to work on the localhost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running facebook application on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a registration problem. Make sure the site url is set correctly, people seem to having a similar issue in [this thread](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=82131).