# Test OAuth Login Redirection for Facebook

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, oauth-2.0

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application that shows information from Facebook. However, if I'm debugging the website locally without a public HTTP endpoint, how can I test the authentication to grab the OAuth token to ensure my app can pull the correct information?

Comment: I've a PHP tutorial about this [here](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-develop-your-facebook-application-locally/6/). It *may* help you get the idea..

Comment: Is it a standalone web app or is it a canvas/iFrame app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean running in localhost . . . take a look at this question:

[Running Facebook application on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost)