# Facebook Canvas URL

Tags: canvas, facebook

i am trying to set up a Facebook Application to get it working on the localhost. i have redirected localhost.com to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts.

i have set up the following

[image]

And when i try to set the canvas url to

[image]

am getting the following error

> Validation failed.
>
> URL must point to a directory (i.e.,
>   end with a '/' or a dynamic page
>   (i.e., have a '?' somewhere). Canvas
>   Page can only contain lowercase
>   letters, dashes, and underscores.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running facebook application on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Canvas Page can only contain lowercase letters, dashes, and underscores.".

You're using a number?

Comment: oh damn. i was trying to look at the canvas url :(

Comment: now it says Validation failed.

URL must point to a directory (i.e., end with a '/' or a dynamic page (i.e., have a '?' somewhere).

Comment: That means that it should be `http://localhost.com/facebook/` or something like `http://localhost.com/facebook/?page=login`

Answer (score 1):

Leave the canvas page blank.  i.e. take out "variable3".

Answer (score 0):

Canvas Page URL: This is the most confusing part, and wasted me heaps of time. What they want you to enter is basically a directory name for your applcaition. The name must be 7 characters or more, and must be unique from other Facebook applications. I used `guessab` (so you can’t). When you add http://apps.facebook.com/ to the front you have the Canvas page URL.

NOTE: If you use upper case in the Canvas Page URL, it will be converted to lower case automatically. Also, case is important, so if you use upper case in your links later on they don't work.
http://gathadams.com/2007/06/18/how-to-write-a-facebook-application-in-10-minutes/