# Facebook connect giving Redirecting Loop

Tags: php, facebook

I am getting Redirecting loop and I am yet unable to figure out where am I doing wrong.

Below are my App Settings:
[image]

**config.php**

```
session_start();
//Facebook App Id and Secret
$appID='xxx';
$appSecret='xxxxxxx';

$base_url = "http://localhost/xxx/fbsource/Source3/facebook/";
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login with Facebook</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/oauthpopup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#facebook').click(function(e){
        $.oauthpopup({
            path: 'login.php',
            width:600,
            height:300,
            callback: function(){
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});


</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['User']) && empty($_SESSION['User']))   { ?>
<img src="images/facebook.png" id="facebook"  style="cursor:pointer;float:left;margin-left:550px;" />
<?php  }  else{

 echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'. $_SESSION['User']['id'] .'/picture" width="30" height="30"/><div>'.$_SESSION['User']['name'].'</div>';   
    echo '<a href="'.$_SESSION['logout'].'">Logout</a>';




}
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php 

require 'config.php';
require 'lib/facebook/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     =>  $appID,
        'secret'    => $appSecret,
        ));
//get the user facebook id      
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$base_url = "http://localhost/xxx/fbsource/Source3/facebook/";
if($user){

    try{
        //get the facebook user profile data
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $params = array('next' => $base_url.'logout.php');
        //logout url
        $logout =$facebook->getLogoutUrl($params);
        $_SESSION['User']=$user_profile;
        $_SESSION['logout']=$logout;
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        error_log($e);
        $user = NULL;
    }       
}

if(empty($user)){
//login url 
$loginurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope'         => 'email,read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos',
                'display'=>'popup'
                'redirect_url'=> $base_url."login.php";
                ));


header('Location: '.$loginurl);

}





?>
<!-- after authentication close the popup -->
<script type="text/javascript">

window.close();

</script>
```

I tested it on both Chrome and IE10

Comment: Any errors? which page has the loop? and you need to remove `session_start();` from `config.php` because facebook php SDK file provides that

Comment: No error. I get redirects on login.php

Comment: Upload your files to public server and it should work because **`localhost`** is unreachable by Facebook

Comment: This is I just figured out. This was not an issue when I made a Facebook app within Facebook Platform. I wonder why is this issue here?

Comment: @AdamAzad please put it as Answer so that Ican accept it.

Comment: Did it work for you? I tested it [Here](http://retrogram.tk/demos/check_id/) it works fine 
I set the `redirect_uri` to `[Project_files]/login.php`

Comment: Localhost did not work, worked on public IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` or `127.0.0.1` is unreachable by Facebook server although It was possible to run Facebook Apps in past on WAMP, LAMP and MAMP (localhost)

- [Running Facebook application on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost)
- [How To: Develop Your Facebook Application Locally](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-develop-your-facebook-application-locally/6/)
- [How can I make Facebook's graph API work on my localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858476/how-can-i-make-facebooks-graph-api-work-on-my-localhost)

But it seems it doesn't work anymore, I faced the same problem while trying to test/debug those files, but the **JS SDK works fine everywhere!**