# https for localhost:8080

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine

I am trying to develop a facebook app written in Python running on Google App Engine, so i need to make my http://localhost:8080 to https://localhost:8080 since facebook is asking for a Secure Canvas URL
how can i make https in localhost:8080 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Secure_URLs):

> The development web server does not
>   support HTTPS connections. It ignores
>   the secure parameter, so paths
>   intended for use with HTTPS can be
>   tested using regular HTTP connections
>   to the development web server.

You can star [issue 960](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=960) to request that support be added. Until then, my advice would be to run Apache or lighttpd as a proxy to the development server, and enable HTTPS on the front-end service only.

Answer (score 8):

I use [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) to proxy my https request on localserver. I run my localserver on
127.0.0.1:8000 and have configured stunnel with

```
[https]
accept  = 8001
connect = 8000
```

so it responds to https on 127.0.0.1:8001. 
I have configured the FB app with the above 2 ips. Works nicely.
For windows, you can find the installer at [here](ftp://stunnel.mirt.net/stunnel/)

You need to configure 2 facebook apps. 1 for the production. 1 for the local.
Use the host ip to return different APP_ID for different apps on local and production.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend deploying with nginx and gunicorn. Super-easy, and you can just make a self-signed cert to use locally. Much faster and easier than Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/) . I think this will answer your question

Add this to your app.yaml

```
handlers:

- url: #url
  script: #script
  login: required
  secure: always
```

more reference [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Secure_URLs)

Comment: i was looking at this, but it will work if you have not activated secure browsing in facebook, if you have activated secure browsing then it will show 
_"Please Update Your Secure Canvas URL"_
so i need to give an https url
if i simply give https://localhost:8080 , it will show SSL error