# Facebook PHP SDK not working on localhost

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running facebook application on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost)

I am trying to start off some standard Facebook integration for my next web-app. This is my CakePHP + Facebook SDK code.

```
$app_id = 'MY_APP_ID';
$secret = 'MY_APP_SECRET';

App::import('Vendor', 'facebook/facebook');
$facebook = new Facebook(array(  'appId'  => $app_id,  'secret' => $secret));    

echo $facebook->getUser();
```

The output this gives me is (even though I'm logged in)

```
0
```

Now from what I've read on the internet the only reason this is happening is because I'm running on `localhost`. I am using the latest version of the SDK.

Is there a fix to this? Ideally I'd like to continue testing on `localhost`.