# Need to simulate facebook iframe locally (local host) while developing my application

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, simulation

Ok , 
While developing facebook application I always had to simulate and test on Facebook Iframe canvas 
it's kinda hard uploading your new code to the host and then debugging (waste of time ) 
is there a way I can simulate the Facebook Iframe Locally 
Like a virtual FaceBook or any IDE for this purpose ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No I need to smiulate the facebook Auth (OAuth ) , or when the facebook says that the user is logged in ... in my local host

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running facebook application on localhost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost)

Comment: It's definitely possible...read the tutorial I linked to in the above answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's nothing to do this. The only reliable way to build & test for platform is to do your development against the actual API.