# Using Facebook Comments in localhost PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, localhost, facebook-comments

I am developing a PHP web application that uses Facebook API to login to my website. Now I am trying to use the Facebook comments plugin in my website. I am developing locally. I am using WAMP server. The url is localhost/www/fbcomments

I can successfully login by using localhost. But for comments, Facebook says the URL is unreachable. Any possible ways to implement Facebook comments plugin locally? Thanks

Comment: You can try reading .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide facebook with your Internet IP Address and set up some information on your router to pass port 80 requests to your pc.