# Facebook application login error on localhost 

Tags: facebook, authentication, localhost

I want to create a Facebook App. I've done everything they specified. 
I have made setup to test application on my localhost as they have specified [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/Facebook#editing_your_app)

I'm getting the index page properly (see the image below). But when I click on Facebook login button, I'm getting the following error

[image]

Why is this so? What should I do? Did I miss something?
I have PHP-sdk of Facebook. and regards

Comment: Do you have any logs about this situation? The errormessage is far from helpful.

Comment: No i don't. Can u please guide me how to set error logs at least some reference??
I'm doing it for the first time.

Comment: I have same application running https://gentle-spring-1141.herokuapp.com/ here on Heroku. even there login is not working

Comment: You actually *can* login from localhost.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost

Answer (score -1):

Try setting App domain ir your App setings. I don't think you can login from localhost.

Comment: if i set an app domain which i have right now i would not be able to test it locally as it would be taken from app domain directly.. m i right?

Now if i want to test it locally it needs login for which i'm facing problems. time to time updating app on domain w/o testing it on local machine doesn't sounds goot to me.
Thanx anyway !! but still not able to solve this