# Setting up Facebook Login on localhost

Tags: php, facebook, localhost, facebook-apps, facebook-login

I've been following the steps outlined here to create a Facebook App Login:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/

And am on Step 3.  I'm setting this up on localhost for development and then I'll publish to Azure Websites with a different App ID.  I'd like to have this working on localhost first though.  (I haven't tried this with a non-localhost domain yet.)

On my Facebook App configuration page I've set a couple relevant fields:
Site URL: http:// localhost : 8052/  (Spaces added to allow submision to Stack Overflow)
App Domains: localhost

main.php redirects to a login page if there is no Facebook code set.  This works fine.

```
<head>
<?php
   if(!isset($_SESSION['code'])) {
      echo ('<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=/login.php" />');
   }
?>
</head>
```

login.php redirects to Facebook's login page using code copied from their example.

```
<?php

   include '/lib/url.php';

   $app_id = "XXXXX";
   $app_secret = "XXXXX";
   $my_url = CreateUrlForPage('welcome.php');

   session_start();

   $code = '';
   if(!isset($_REQUEST["code"])) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); // CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo $my_url.'<br/>';
     echo $dialog_url.'<br/>';
     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }
?>
```

Clearly I've obfuscated my App ID above.

The URL generated by my "CreateUrlForPage" function looks fine as does the facebook login URL:

```
http://localhost:8052/welcome.php
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8052%2Fwelcome.php&state=XXXX
```

(Again, some obfuscation here.  The real values looked okay.  The first being an integer the second being a long hex string.)

When I navigate to http:// localhost : 8052/login.php, The page redirects to Facebook and gives a completely useless error: "An error occurred.  Please try again later."

I looked at a couple other posts on Stack Overflow, but they didn't solve my problem.

The error I'm getting looks just like the one described here:
[Facebook application login error on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654396/facebook-application-login-error-on-localhost) 
The suggestion provided is to set the Domain and Site URL, which I've done.

There is also a link to this question: [Running Facebook application on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost)
Again, they suggest Site URL.  They also talk about app-canvas which is not something I'm using and I don't see how it would be related to login.

For what it's worth, before I set the Site URL and Domain, I was getting a different error - one that told me I needed to set the Site URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code worked for me. double check your facebook app id and my site url is set to  http:// localhost:8052/ dont really need to set domain name for login thanks

http://gamma.owlweb.com.ua/index.php/?route=account/register/fb

```
<?php

$app_id = "xxx";    $app_secret = "xxx"; 
$my_url ="http://localhost:3080/abc.php";

session_start();

$code = '';    

if(!isset($_REQUEST["code"])) {
  $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); // CSRF protection
  $dialog_url = 
    "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=".$app_id
    ."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($my_url)
    ."&state=".$_SESSION['state'];

  echo $my_url.'<br/>';
  echo $dialog_url.'<br/>';
  echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
} 
?>
```

Comment: I think the App I was using was busted.  I created a new App on Facebook and it worked fine.  The old one I was using I had created about 10 years ago and never did anything with it.  Maybe something changed since then...