# How to build facebook login for Rhomobile Application?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, rhomobile, rhodes

I want to build Facebook login to my Rhomobile app. Coding languages are html, JS, Ruby. Therefore can not use Android sdk or iOS sdk. JS sdk gives the error "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration".
Reason for this is app running on local server with random port.
eg.: http://127.0.0.1:24738/

I did it previously using redirection service rediectme.to. But this service is not running anymore.

Anyone has working example for this?

Comment: I think this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667180/setting-up-facebook-login-on-localhost

Answer (score 0):

One way may be to use other frameworks that have already done this within your application. Example using parse.com JS library:

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-facebook-users

You can also use facebook REST API as described in this post (disregard the note about the Cordova specific plugin which uses native libraries, but pay attention to the part that talks about the 3rd method that uses Fb rest APIs)

http://kmturley.blogspot.com/2014/10/facebook-login-inside-hybrid-app-using.html