# Facebook login with JavaScript SDK error: "redirect URI not whitelisted"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I want my website to login with facebook but I am seeing this error.

> Given URL is not whitelisted in Client OAuth Settings: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
      // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
      function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);
        // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
        // app know the current login status of the person.
        // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
        // for FB.getLoginStatus().
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
          // Logged into your app and Facebook.
          testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
          // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            'into this app.';
        } else {
          // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
          // they are logged into this app or not.
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
            'into Facebook.';
        }
      }

      // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
      // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
      // code below.
      function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
      }

      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
          appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                            // the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v2.5' // use version 2.2
      });

      // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
      // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
      // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
      // the callback you provide.  They can be:
      //
      // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
      // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
      // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
      //    your app or not.
      //
      // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });

      };

      // Load the SDK asynchronously
      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

      // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
      // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
      function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
            'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
        });
      }
    </script>

    <!--
      Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
      the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
      the FB.login() function when clicked.
    -->

    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
    </fb:login-button>

    <div id="status">
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where is your url being declared?

Comment: In the app. Site URL section

Comment: When you run this do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors. but i see same thing in the console log  Given URL is not whitelisted in Client OAuth Settings: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

Answer (score 7):

You must make sure you have registered your app with the developer page

[Go here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)

For the facebook login docs

[Go here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login)

Then when you register your app make sure whatever URL you are using as the redirect page is the same as your app is sending too.

For example
http://example.com
is not,
http://www.example.com

To settup url as the local host refer to
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14667609/2218253)

Please make sure you are setting your

```
$app_id = "xxx"; 
$app_secret = "xxx"; 
$my_url ="http://localhost:3080/example.php";
```

All to the correct data as specified inside your app settings when you create your app on facebook's developer page.

To make this as clear as possible.

Go to your app page and enter the url of the page in your localhost.
Then go to your code and add the exact same url.

in app settings,

```
http://localhost
```

in your code

```
http://localhost
```

If there is a port number after your localhost,

in app settings,

```
http://localhost:8080
```

in your code

```
http://localhost:8080
```

If there is a file after your localhost

in app settings,

```
http://localhost/myfile.php
```

in your code

```
    http://localhost/myfile.php
```

Please try this code. replace your code with this code and do not forget to change the

`YOUR_FACBEOOK_APP_ID`

to your own.

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
            appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));

    function login() {
        FB.login(function(response) {

        // handle the response
        console.log("Response goes here!");

        }, {scope: 'read_stream,publish_stream,publish_actions,read_friendlists'});            
    }

    function logout() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
          // user is now logged out
        });
    }

    var status = FB.getLoginStatus();

    console.log(status);

    </script>

    <button onclick="javascript:login();">Login Facebook</button>

    <br>

    <button onclick="javascript:logout();">Logout from Facebook</button>
```

Comment: I have registered an app. that app is live and running and not sure what i have missed .it'snot working

Comment: It complains Given URL is not whitelisted in Client OAuth Settings: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings . what i need to do

Comment: Yes i am using the correct url

Comment: i have registered with http

Comment: yes, all are with http://www

Comment: both in the app and the register are with http.www

Comment: Does my app need to be reviewed before it gets worked?

Comment: I am testing that feature in my localmachine. so it runs on the localhost. after i click the login button  url turns out to be like this ....https://www.facebook.com/v2.5/dialog/oauth?scope=public_profile%2Cemail&response_type=none&seen_revocable_perms_nux=false&ref=LoginButton&auth_type=&default_audience&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Freturn%2Farbiter%3Frelation%3Dopener%26close%3Dtrue%23origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A51295%252Ff3254eb244&state=f135f4cacc&app_id=23&client_id=2342342424&display=popup

Comment: what i need to provide to test in localhost. Could u tell me briefly what i need to do .suppose if my website name http://www.test123.com.  what urls i need to give in the app

Comment: I am using the same piece of code that is there in the facebook website and just added my app id. when i am trying to log in it's not working

Comment: Please post the code so I can look at it.

Comment: I have posted the code below please check it

Comment: I have used the above code that u posted. I am seeing the same error.

Comment: Please try this updated code. change out your app id

Comment: Still i am seeing the same error

Comment: Show me the exact url from facebook settings

Comment: Why would one need to whitelist a redirect uri anyway? This is an in-browser workflow with facebook's javascript sdk. There is no callback to be provided, and indeed Facebook's own sample code doesn't provide one either. I'm seeing the same effect after I switched web oath off in the settings. Very odd.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, modifying the /etc/hosts file to map '127.0.0.1' to something like myapp.com - so that your application has a “real” URL, resolved the issue. 
Same is to be added to "Valid OAuth redirect URIs"  in the Client OAuth Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem . 
For me the solution was to add both WWW and no-WWW versions of my site to whitelist in Client OAuth Settings.