# facebook login error: URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

In my rails app i have added facebook login using Omniauth
I created my app and everything was good on localhost but then i added my url on Valid OAuth redirect URIs and started getting this error:

```
URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.
```

My valid outh redirect url is: `http://www.greyshift.co/profiles/new`

My domain name is: `www.greyshift.co`
My site url is: `http://www.greyshift.co/`

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37001004/facebook-login-message-url-blocked-this-redirect-failed-because-the-redirect or try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477847/facebook-login-with-javascript-sdk-error-redirect-uri-not-whitelisted and tell me whether it works or not

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined app domain at https://developers.facebook.com as its as you are sending in request

```
http://www.greyshift.co/
```

`http://www.greyshift.co/` is different from `http://www.greyshift.co`

Also at "Add platform" option at basic setting, select website and provide your Site URL

Answer (score 0):

You need to see to what your login with Facebook button is linking (you may need to decode it ) :

in my case it is : https://web.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/api/auth/facebook/callback&scope=email&client_id=347056379050229&_rdc=1&_rdr

this is the redirect_uri : http://localhost:3000/api/auth/facebook/callback

Put it in the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field, which
You can access from app -> Facebook Login -> settings