# Can I map a hostname *and* a port with /etc/hosts?

Tags: linux, dns, port, hostname

Can I map an IP address like `127.0.0.1` to a domain name *and* a port?

For example, I would like to map `127.0.0.1` to `api.example.com:8000`

Comment: You cannot map the port number in /etc/hosts. Instead you can define as `127.0.0.1  api.mydomain.com` and access it in the browser like `api.mydomain.com:8080`

Comment: I read somewhere that dns supports this. You can have a record that says on www.example.com http is on port 80 and also an A record to say that the address is 127.0.0.1 it also said it was not well supported. It did not say much after that.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The port is not part of the hostname, so it has no meaning in the `hosts`-file.

Answer (score 172):

If you really need to do this, use a reverse proxy. For example, with Nginx:

```
server {
  listen       api.mydomain.com:80;
  server_name  api.mydomain.com;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the line of proxy_pass should look like this: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;` I got "invalid URL prefix" on nginx 1.4.3.

Comment: thanks for this wonderful tip! simple solution for most servers.

Comment: I am using this trick to map ports of a remote machine (e.g. http://cloud.app:80 while the actual port is 8080). Very useful for testing Confluence nodes of a cluster but accessing them on the same base URL. Thanks!

Comment: I had basically the same problem and the solution using this reverse-proxy is really helpful. Although, I wanted some simpler solution so I made this tool: https://github.com/cristianoliveira/ergo 

I hope it help in somehow :)

Comment: Thanks @CristianOliveira ! This helped me a LOT :)