# How to redirect from a webpack-dev-server to a custom domain from hosts?

Tags: webpack, localhost, webpack-dev-server, host, hosts

I replaced the domain in the hosts file
**127.0.0.1:8080 domain.com**

But it did not help

This is my webpack.config

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true,
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 80
    },
});
```

Comment: `/etc/hosts` does not support port specification, only domain:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729034/can-i-map-a-hostname-and-a-port-with-etc-hosts

Comment: @PavelDenisjuk thanks Pavel already got it
So can I make somethink like this another way?

Comment: Since I don't have access to your project, I tried to replicate the problem with create-react-app project, and successfully linked it with an actual domain name. `/etc/hosts` contains the `127.0.0.1 mydomain.com` mapping and devServer has a port `80`. Had to start it with `sudo` because it is a port below `1024`, but it did work. If you could provide a github repo it would be easier to help you out.