# Uncaught OAuthException: This IP can't make requests for that application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

i am trying to configure facebook php sdk on localhost and trying to run example.php

i have changed app id and secret

my app domain is localhost
and site url is 
localhost/facebook-php-sdk-master/examples/

what error i get is
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: This IP can't make requests for that application. thrown in C:\wamp\www\facebook-php-sdk-master\src\base_facebook.php on line 1334

I am not able to resolve it.

and also sometimes i get the error
Uncaught CurlException: 35: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to graph.facebook.com

if anyone has any idea how to configure it on localhost, please help me.

thanks in advance

Comment: Give this a look, may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133075/running-facebook-application-on-localhost

Comment: i have seen almost all the stackoverflow queries, but nothing worked

Answer (score 8):

Remove any IP address that you have whitelisted in your app setting's advanced tab.